# Tornado chat with SockJS and Redis

Tags: python, redis, tornado

I have Tornado chat with export to Redis. Other scripts will export messages from Redis to MongoDB in the time. It works, but how is it written?

```
def tornadoredis_client():
    client = tornadoredis.Client(*configuration.REDIS_CONFIG)
    client.connect()
    return client


class PlansqTornadoChat(SockJSConnection):
    users = dict()
    timezones = dict()

    def on_open(self, info):
        self.authenticated = False
        self.timezone = None
        self.client = tornadoredis_client()

    @tornado.gen.engine
    def on_message(self, msg):
        data = proto.json_decode(msg)

        if data['type'] == 'auth':
            if bool(data.get('sid', None)):
                try:
                    int(data['sid'])  # check that sid is number, not word
                    self.user_sid = data['sid']
                    self.users[self.user_sid] = self
                    self.user_timezone = yield tornado.gen.Task(self.client.hget, 'timezones', self.user_sid)
                    self.timezones[self.user_sid] = self.user_timezone
                    self.authenticated = True
                    self.send(proto.json_encode({"body": "You was authorized", 'type': 'alert'}))
                except Exception, e:
                    logging.info("bad user's sid: " + str(data['sid']))
            else:
                self.send(proto.json_encode({"body": "You did not authorize", 'type': 'alert'}))
                self.close()

        elif data['type'] == 'message':
            if all([x in data for x in ['type', 'recipient', 'body', 'sender']]) \
                    and data['sender'] == self.user_sid:
                recipient = data['recipient']

                try:
                    int(recipient)  # check that sid is number, not word
                except Exception, e:
                    logging.info('sid of recipient is not number')
                    return

                self.thread = "_".join([str(x) for x in sorted([int(self.user_sid), int(recipient)])])

                # Save to Redis
                data_to_send = {
                    'thread_id': self.thread,
                    'sender': self.user_sid,
                    'recipient': recipient,
                    'body': data['body'],
                    'datetime': (datetime.now() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
                }

                yield tornado.gen.Task(self.client.sadd, "thread:" + self.thread, proto.json_encode(data_to_send))
                yield tornado.gen.Task(self.client.sadd, 'new_threads:all', "thread:" + self.thread)

                # Send to Socket
                data_to_send['type'] = 'message'

                # if user is online
                if recipient in self.users:
                    data_to_send['datetime'] = utc_to_localtime(data_to_send['datetime'], self.timezones[recipient])
                    self.users[recipient].send(proto.json_encode(data_to_send))

                data_to_send['datetime'] = utc_to_localtime(data_to_send['datetime'], self.user_timezone)
                self.send(proto.json_encode(data_to_send))

            else:
                logging.info('Bad request: ' + str(data))
        else:
            logging.info('Bad request: ' + str(data))

    def on_close(self):
        del self.users[self.user_sid]
        del self.timezones[self.user_sid]
        self.client.disconnect()
```

My configuration in configuration of main application (Flask + MongoDB). There only Redis configuration (host and port).

The rest of the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    EchoRouter = SockJSRouter(PlansqTornadoChat, '/socket')

    app = web.Application(EchoRouter.urls)
    app.listen(configuration.TORNADO_PORT)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some notes on Pythonic style.

People usually instantiate an empty `dict` with `{}`, instead of actually calling `dict()`. Usually, the only reason you need to call `dict` is if you're passing some variables to create your dictionary.

There's no need to explicitly cast a value to a boolean, Python can implicitly run a boolean test on any type. So you can just do this:

```
if data.get('sid', None):
```

I don't know exactly what type `data` is, but assuming it's a dictionary, `get` will default to returning `None`, so there's no need to make it an explicit parameter of `get`.

You have a long block inside a `try` followed by a blanket `except Exception, e`. There's a few problems here. First, your `try` block should be as narrow as possible. You can use `return` to prematurely end functions from the `except` block if you need to. Speaking of that `except` block, you should ensure that it's only catching errors you specifically expect. In this case, presumably you want to catch `ValueError`s from a bad `data['sid']` string, as well as catching `KeyError` for `user_sid`s that don't show up in the `users` dictionary. Blanket `exceptions` will just mask errors you're not expecting, instead of handling the ones you know can occur in normal execution.

Lastly, don't use `except Exception, e` syntax, it will lead to trouble and was removed in Python 3. It causes ambiguities when you want to catch multiple exception types, like `except KeyError, ValueError, e:`. How is Python supposed to interpret that? This is why you should use `except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:` or `except (KeyError, ValueError):`, as you don't *have* to store the result in a variable if you're not using it.